# GCC - windows - no input files

Tags: windows-7, python, gcc

I am trying to install GCC on a windows 7, 64bit machine in order to run a specific package (theano) on python 2.7.

at the moment - when i type gcc --version at the command prompt - i get the response "gcc (tmd64-1) 5.1.0".

however - when i just type gcc - i get a message "gcc: fatal error: no input files. compilation terminated".

I am a noob with regards to matters - let me know what steps i might want to take.

Many thanks in advance, W

Comment: gcc is a compiler, it requires input files.  Otherwise, it has nothing to do.  What are you trying to achieve by running gcc other than checking the version you have installed?

Comment: [Quickie Intro to GCC](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse451/99wi/Section/gccintro.html)

Comment: It's basically expecting you to pass it an argument to tell it what you want it to do. You call the program, then you tell it what to do.  You type in `gcc --version`, it says, oh here's the version. You call the program only, and don't tell it what you want it to do, it has an error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GCC is installed just fine, you just didn't have any input files to give it, and GCC does not have an interactive prompt like Python does.

It should be OK to go ahead and try your Python package now.